# shift matrix columns in c

Tags: c, matrix

how can i shift each column of a matrix to the left by the row number ?
for example

```
 0, 1, 2, 3
 4, 5, 6, 7
 8, 9,10,11
12,13,14,15
```

this is a 4*4 matrix, the index of the first row is 0, therefore the columns will not move,
the second row's index is 1, therefore each column will move 1 spot to the left (cyclically).
the output for the given matrix is
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfUiZ.png)

my function code is:

```
void ShiftRows(int message[M][M])
{
    int temp = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < M ; i++) 
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
        {
            temp = message[i][(j-i)%M];
            message[i][(j-i)%M] = message[i][j];
            message[i][j] = temp;
        } 
        temp = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only swap 2 values. That does not work for cyclically shift a whole row.

```c
void ShiftRows(int message[M][M])
{
    for (int i = 1; i < M ; i++) 
    {
        int temp[M];
        // First shift using a copy
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
        {
            temp[j] = message[i][(j+i)%M];
        }

        // After whole row is shifted, copy back
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
        {
            message[i][j] = temp[j];
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: that makes a lot of sense. thank you for your reply !